# Problem with this keyword and addEventHandler function

Tags: javascript, html

I've a problem with adding a class to HTML element in JS.

I want to create some kind of accordion, but I have no idea what I am doing wrong (at first I should say that I don't have much experience with JS). This is what HTML element that I'm using looks like:

```
<div class="account_content_orders_list_order">
  <div class="account_content_orders_list_order_element"></div>
  <div class="account_content_orders_list_order_element"></div>
  <div class="account_content_orders_list_order_element"></div>
  <div class="account_content_orders_list_order_element"></div>
  <div class="account_content_orders_list_order_element"></div>
  <div class="account_content_orders_list_order_element"></div>
  <div class="account_content_orders_list_order_element"></div>
</div>
```

And this is my script in JS:

```
  let orders = document.getElementsByClassName("account_content_orders_list_order");

  for (let k = 0; k < orders.length; k++) {
    orders[k].addEventListener("click", () => {
      this.classList.add("active_order");
    });
  }
```

But when I click on the HTML Element I am getting an error in Chrome console:
[image: JS ERROR]

I wanted to check if *this* keyword points at correct DOM Element so I added *console.log(this);* to the loop I showed you above, but I know now that is somehow problem with *this* keyword which points at *window* object and I don't know why.
[image: THIS POINTS WRONG]

Can someone give any advice? I'm out of ideas.
Sorry if it's duplicate, I couldn't find any topic similar to mine.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrow functions don't have their own `this`. Use standard function:

```js
orders[k].addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.classList.add("active_order");
});
```

If you really want to use arrow function, you can go with `event.currentTarget`:

```js
orders[k].addEventListener("click", event => {
    event.currentTarget.classList.add("active_order");
});
```

`addEventListener()` injects `event.currentTarget` as `this`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer works. I have to wait a few minutes to accept your answer but I'm gonna do that. Thanks again.